# Including Python Script Dependencies (virtualenv contents) in Platypus

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, python

I'm trying to turn a python script into a OS X App that you can run directly from Finder. I'm trying out [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus), which seemed like the simplest option. The problem I'm running into is with the packages I'm including in the script. I installed them through pip into a virtualenv. Wondering what the best/most proper way to include those files in the Platypus bundle would be. I know I could just copy them over to the same directory and include them in the Platypus bundle, but would prefer to do something cleaner like including the virtualenv, although it seems like that would then have to be installed by the users of the app.

I also ran into [py2app](http://pythonhosted.org/py2app/) which seems to be able to achieve something similar to Platypus, but their documentation is somewhat obscure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I've solved this is in the past is by bundling the contents of the `virtualenv` directory into Platypus and then activating the bundled Python interpreter with a script.

Here's a screencap of the Platypus interface to show you what I mean:

[image: Platypus window setup]

You'll notice that I've bundled the entire `venv` directory (which was created with the `virtualenv` command), and my Python script, `my_app.py`.

The script that I'm actually telling Platypus to run, `run.sh`, is a shell script with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

"$PWD/venv/bin/python" my_app.py "$@"
```

All this script does is use the `python` binary in the `venv` directory to run the bundled Python script. The `"$@"` is there to pass any arguments to `run.sh` directly into `my_app.py` without changing them.

Comment: This doesn't really work, because Python keeps searching for its DLLs in system directories.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a better run.sh --->

```
#!/bin/bash

# Save the current directory
CURRENT_DIR=$(pwd)

# Change to the virtual environment directory (adjust the path as necessary)
cd venv

# Activate the virtual environment
source bin/activate


# Change back to the original directory
cd "$CURRENT_DIR"

# Run the Python script
python3 app.py

# Optionally, deactivate the virtual environment
# deactivate
```